# WebBrowser In code name one

Tags: codenameone

I am new in Code name one.

I want to display http://www.google.com in web browser in my app.
Here is my code for calling web page in browser.

```
    


    WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
    browser.setWidth(300);
    browser.setHeight(300);
    browser.setBrowserNavigationCallback(new BrowserNavigationCallback()
    {
        public boolean shouldNavigate(String url)
        {

            return true;
        }
    });
    subCenterContainer.addComponent(browser);
    browser.setURL("https://www.google.com");
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
 subCenterContainer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 subCenterContainer.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);
 browser.setURL("https://www.google.com");
```

Don't set things like absolute sizes, that won't work in Codename One. You need to use layout managers for that.

Comment: Thanks sir, Its working now. But what if i want to set width and height of component at run time because in android the pixel density and handset's width/height is different device to device and brand to brand. In that case we have to change width/height of images and buttons according to screen. So please suggest what i do in it for this case.

Comment: That is exactly the reason why you should use layout managers and not set width/height. If you want to work with all resolutions you should avoid the web browser and use Codename One properly with multi-images, image borders and layout managers see the how do I section in the website http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i.html

Comment: Hi sir, I am using multi-images and and 9 part images but as i make UI check them own Galaxy s2 but when i put it in my friend's galaxy duos its structure is distracted. i was happy that finally i made 1 UI but it feel little sadness. I will work on it to make it more reliable for multi screens. But i have a question that make me confuse that if we make changes in UI in java file with calculation at run time that made in resource file, them are we breaking rule of MVC model? My senior said yes but i am not aggry with him. Please help me in my dought. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the Codename One demos such as Kitchen Sink and see how they adapt to the various device resolutions seamlessly.